# How to write recursive function javascript push my array property Json object?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the json inner property "Steps". Inner "Steps" i have a new property "Steps". And infiniti.. How to write function, foreach all "steps" property and push start_location and end_location to myArr.

I can write code through forEach, but i don't think it's right.

Please? help

```
{
    [
        {
            "start_location": {
                "lat": 55.757394599999998,
                "lng": 37.6325626
            },
            "end_location": {
                "lat": 55.736126800000001,
                "lng": 37.592756799999997
            },
            "steps": [
                {
                    "start_location": {
                        "lat": 55.757394599999998,
                        "lng": 37.6325626
                    },
                    "end_location": {
                        "lat": 55.757203399999987,
                        "lng": 37.631541800000001
                    },
                    "steps": [
                        {
                            "start_location": {
                                "lat": 55.757205778493002,
                                "lng": 37.631539696071997
                            },
                            "end_location": {
                                "lat": 55.735556776788997,
                                "lng": 37.594390710771997
                            },
                            "steps": [
                                {
                                    "start_location": {
                                        "lat": 55.757205778493002,
                                        "lng": 37.631539696071997
                                    },
                                    "end_location": {
                                        "lat": 55.735556776788997,
                                        "lng": 37.594390710771997
                                    },
                                },
                                {
                                    "start_location": {
                                        "lat": 55.757205778493002,
                                        "lng": 37.631539696071997
                                    },
                                    "end_location": {
                                        "lat": 55.735556776788997,
                                        "lng": 37.594390710771997
                                    },
                                },
                            ]
                        },

                        ......
                    ]
                },

                ....
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what are you looking for in the nested structure? please add what you have tried.

Comment: Mind sharing the `forEach` code you tried that you say isn't right?

Comment: @StefanOctavian: you should read [the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) before posting comments.

Comment: Please provide a valid json/object data, this one is not well structured.

Comment: @georg, I hadn't meant to be rude, I just wanted to tell OP that I hadn't really understood what he asked and that he should improve his english. I'm sorry if I said something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this simple function:

```
function enumerate(x, fn) {
    if (x && typeof x === 'object') {
        for (let val of Object.values(x)) {
            fn(val);
            enumerate(val, fn);
        }
    }
}
```

It walks through a nested object structure and invokes the given callback for each value it finds (no matter object or primitive). You can apply it to your structure and provide a callback that analyzes the value and, if it has the needed properties, adds it to an array, for example:

```
enumerate(yourData, function (val) {
    if (val.start_location)
        yourArray.push([val.start_location, val.end_location])
});
```

Hope this helps you getting started, good luck!